# Need Latest Version of Salesforce APK file

Tags: mobilesdk, salesforce-mobile-app

We are having around 150 users who are using old Salesforce Mobile version and we want to update them to Latest Salesforce version as they are having Android Legacy MDM device they cant update Salesforce directly from Playstore. Hence we would need a trusted source of latest Salesforce APK  so that we can provide it to business and they would install it in end users devices.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce will never provide [apk file](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000330588&type=1&mode=1) directly. It is always recommended to install via Apple Store or Google Play Store.  However, if you do not have access to Google Play Store you can download manually [here](https://salesforce1android.herokuapp.com/).

I would recommended to reach out to your internal team and Install Salesforce Mobile version app from Google play store on your corporate device.

Check more details on [MDM setup and support](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000340176&type=1&mode=1).

Thanks